# How to stop a process named "Code" that has high CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, process

I have one process named "Code" that has high CPU usage. I don't know what this process is and how I can stop it.

[image: "Code" process in System Monitor]

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: isn't this VSCode ?

Comment: Yes, it really was VSCode. It is strange that he loaded the CPU so much, and it was closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely VS Code. You can kill the process from a terminal using the following command:

```
killall code
```

Or, since you know the ID of the process (it's shown in the screenshot you provided):

```
kill -9 9661
```

You can also <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the process in System Monitor and select *Kill*.

Comment: It really was VSCode, I reinstall it and the problem is gone, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

ps - aux | grep code

kill {id}

Answer (score 0):

by the name of the process you can use the console command

```
pkill <process name>
```

the documentation is [written here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Answer (score -2):

Recommended distribution of VS Code for Ubuntu is through deb.

So if that snap is not depended by any other application, then remove it

`snap remove code`

and [install VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: Yes, it really was VS Code. Reinstalling helped. Thank you!